# Moving a partition without gparted

Tags: linux, partitioning, ext4, headless

I need to move (shift) an ext4 partition on my disk in a headless Linux machine, like this:

```
Before:
[######### Partition #########][- Free space -]

After:
[- Free space -][######### Partition #########]
```

This task is straightforward when using `GParted`, however any advices I've found for headless hosts consist of installing a VNC server and Gparted with all of its dependencies. I can not believe that there is no unix-way console tool for moving partitions around or a manual for doing the same with `dd` or something similar. Any thoughts please?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu great, that's what I was looking for. Indeed, I should have asked at Superuser. Can you please post your comment as an answer so I could mark it accepted?

Comment: I'm glad that you found what you were looking for. Thank you for the intention of giving me some points, but there's no need for it, since I believe that this question belongs on Super User and voted accordingly (you can probably vote for this too since it's your own question).

Answer (score 1):

How about just plain parted? It have `move` as one of its operations. Have a look at the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_chapter/parted_2.html#SEC20).

All you need to do is figure out exactly where the partition should start in the moved state, i.e. the offset from the beginning of the disk (in megabytes).

Comment: Thank you, that's a good suggestion, however, after reading the [documentation for the current version](http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/parted.html#Command-explanations) I found that the option has been removed: "Note that after version 2.4, the following commands were removed: check, cp, mkfs, mkpartfs, move, resize."